# Car revving too high in 5th gear on the highway

Tags: transmission, fiat, sienna, rev-limiter

I drive a 2009 fiat sienna and just did my first highway drive in it and noticed it revs at 4000rpm at 130kmh. 3800 at 120kmh
is this normal? Cause it always sounds like it needs another gear. Acceleration is fine.

Comment: A 5 L won't turn so fast. My 5.6 Nissan Titan turned about 1600 at 120 kmh.

Comment: Did this just start recently, or has it always been like that? If it has changed what RPMs did it cruise at before? Is this an automatic or manual, and what size engine is it?

Comment: Does this car have a tachometer?  If so, where on the gauge does the red zone appear on the dial? I’m assuming 5,500 rpm or so?  That should be your guide on keeping the engine “safe from damage”.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a smaller engine 1 to 1.5 litres then sounds about right.

My car is 2.2 litres and 120kmh is about 2000rpm and 135knmh is about 2200. Has a 6 speed box (plus reverse).